# Migrating TFS2010 Sprint Dates to TFS2012 Iteration Path based dates

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, mdx

We recently migrated TFS 2010 sprint dates to TFS 2012 Iteration Path based dates. Made tsql code changes for reports extracting data from Tfs Warehouse. There are many reports using cube as data source . Will this sprint date migration have any impact on cube? Should the MDX code be changed for these reports?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iteration dates do not get loaded into the data warehouse or cube. You only have access through the API.

Jeff Levinson has done a bunch of work with the tabular model for analysis services and TFS and has created a customs solution that does include this data.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/68f3c013-4e46-43f8-a545-c67d2f9042c2